# Facebook friend list select all UIButton

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

I have integrated in my app the send request feature, which gives you a list of frinds to choose from. How can I add a button which says select all, to select all of the users friends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to build your own version of the friend selector in order to customize the UI. That means recreating the UI, the API calls to fetch the friend lists and send invitations.

Comment: @Alessandro Unfortunately no. The dialog is loaded into a web view from the Facebook website, so no editing it.